# Redirecting caller to a proxy number

Tags: twilio

I have this scenario:

```
Vendor: Restaurant, Delivery Guy, etc
Customer: The one who ordered the food

Constraint: We only know the customer number
```

As I understood, to create a working communication between Vendor and Customer through a Proxy Number, we need to create a session between them. It's important to emphasize here that we don't know who might be the Vendor here or to be more accurate we want Vendor to be anybody who has the correct code. So, that's going to be a little bit of a challenge in this whole proxy number implementation. But we do a plan to solve this situation.

We're planning to give a general number for our vendors to call so that they can input the digit that was provided much more earlier. So, when they called, our server will return this TwiML:

```xml
<Response>
  <Gather action="/process_digits" method="POST">
    <Say>Please input code</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

Our endpoint will then match the code provided in our database (which already has information about the customer) thus allowing our server to create a session between the caller and the customer. This is happening when the vendor is calling the general phone number

```xml
<Response>
  <Say>You entered 1,2,3,4. I'm going to connect you to the customer</Say>
  <Dial callerId="445 (vendor number)">999 (proxy phone number)</Dial>
</Response>
```

As you can see, the response will dial the customer number and set the proxy number as the caller ID. This will ensure the confidentiality of the caller and the receiver. At least that's what we planned.

```
Vendor -> General Phone Number -> Proxy Number -> Customer
```

I've coded all of these but it seems like I won't be redirected to the caller phone number. Twilio just doesn't seem to dial the number. To ensure the proxy session is working, I tried calling the proxy number directly without going through the general number and it did manage to connect to the customer (this is after the session has been created).

Maybe it doesn't work as I'm using the different project in order to create two phone numbers, one number per project (we're in the process to get regulatory bundle approval), but I'm just guessing.

So, the main question is whether this is possible with Twilio and if it's not, do you have any good suggestions on how we can approach this.

Thanks for reading and do let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: The parties should communicate through their assigned Proxy channels, once the Proxy session is set-up. So in your example, after the Proxy session is set-up, the vendor would initiate a call from their CallerID to the Proxy phone number assigned when you set-up the Proxy session with the Customer. The customer will then get a call from their assigned Proxy channel (as the CallerID) to their device. I have not tried your approach of programmatically making that call.

Comment: @Alan I made a mistake with the example. The `Dial` verb would actually call the proxy number and pass the caller as the caller ID. I assume that would allow the proxy number to automatically connect to the customer (which is not the case). Have you tried something like this before?

Comment: I seem to remember doing this and it not working, the Proxy conversation had to be set-up outside Twilio rather then initiated by Twilio but I have not worked that much with Proxy.